# Codeigniter getting the number of results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use Codigniter.

I return results from database using this line:

```
return $query->result_array();
```

In my controller I write following code to get those results:

```
$data["results"] = $this->model_abc->get_them();
```

I would like to know which line I should write in my controller to get the number of results as well.

Could you please help me.

Comment: just posted my answer see it will solve your problem 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the no of row from this

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');
echo $query->num_rows();
```

EDIT

If you want to count the $data["results"], you can use php `count()` function

Comment: Like this?  $data['results_number'] = count($data["results"]);

Comment: getting error with following Message: Undefined variable: results_number

Comment: Probably you store the count on $data['results_number'] and trying to access $results_number. $results_number=count($data["results"]); will solve your problem in this case

Comment: tried in that way also, passed to the view in the following way but still get undefined variable: $this->load->view("view_results",$data,$results_number);

Comment: You would do $this->load->view('view_results',$data); .  Specify results_number as $data['results_number'] and in your view echo out $results_number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller:

// get the results
$data["results"] = $this->model_abc->get_them();

// get count of results
$count = count($data["results"]);

Comment: it's strange but I get Undefined variable error while passing $count variable to the view

Comment: How are you passing the count variable to your view?

Comment: $this->load->view("view_results",$data,$count);

Comment: $this->load->view("view_results",array('count'=>$count));

Comment: but I need to pass $data["results"] as well

Comment: try:  $this->load->view("view_results",array('count'=>$count, 'results'=>$results));

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in the general way

Model:

```
// general purpose counting rows
    function get_them($table ,$where=NULL)
    {
        if(!empty($where))
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }

        $query=$this->db->get($table);

        if($query)
        {
            return $query->num_rows();
        }
        else
        {
            return array();
        }
    }

   // general purpose fetching rows
    function get_records($table ,$where=NULL)
    {
        if(!empty($where))
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }

        $query=$this->db->get($table);

        if($query)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return array();
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
$data['counter']=$this->model_abc->get_them('tablename');
$data['results']=$this->model_abc->get_records('tablename');
$this->load->view('view',$data);
```

View:

```
if(isset($counter))
{
  echo $counter;
}

   if(isset($result))
    {
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
      //YOUR RECORDS
      }
    }
```

I Hope this will work fine for you and i hope it clears out your concept

Comment: I need to display the results and their number

Comment: ok you could use count function as well or you could make separate function for result ok i am going to edit my answer